# How Selective Color and Color Balance filter of Photoshop work?

Tags: ios, image-processing, colors, photoshop

Hi everyone 
 I am newbie in image processing. I want to do some color change filter on IOS just like "selective color" and "color balance" in photoshop. However, I don't know the algorithm of these awesome features. 
I tried find in source code of Paint.Net but unfortunately, PainDotNet does not have this feature .

With color balance, I tried this link [color balance on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781603/color-balance-on-the-iphone) but the result is not good. It's different with photoshop's result.

So anybody know the algorithm of two techniques: selective color and Color balance?

Thanks u and sorry about my complicate presentation

Comment: For Selective Color, see this article: https://blog.pkh.me/p/22-understanding-selective-coloring-in-adobe-photoshop.html
For Color Balance seems to otherwise be the focus of the answers in this question, but there doesn't seem to be anything satisfactory yet.

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to find a solution for this for 2 days now, got some results but they are different from Photoshop implementation and I'm afraid not exactly correct.

The way I'm trying to approach it is to convert RGB color to HSL color space and then adjust Hue and Saturation color values along different axis (Cyan/Red, Yellow/Blue, Green/Magenta).
I'm doing this by using cartesian coordinate system instead of polar one, as described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Hue_and_chroma

My idea is that in cartesian coordinate space (with alpha and beta axis) changing alpha results in modifying color along Cyan/Red axis. Changing color along yellow/blue axis can be achieved by modifying alpha and beta at the same time:

`alpha = alpha + adjustment * cos(PI/3)` 
`beta = beta + adjustment * sin(PI/3)`

Same can be done for other axes. 
After you got new alpha and beta values you can convert them to HSL and then to RGB.

Unfortunately the result is still quiet different from Photoshop implementation. Also I can't figure out the proper way to adjust only Reds, Yellows, Neutrals, Blacks, etc without touching the rest of the colours.

Does anyone have any hints on how this type of adjustment can be achieved?

**Update:**
Here's a discussion about color balance filter in GIMP and Photoshop:
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/193

And here is sample code recreating GIMP color balance filter as a shader: 
https://gist.github.com/3168961 
It's only implemented for midtones at the moment, but it should be pretty straight forward to make changes for highlights and shadows.
Unfortunately GIMP's color balance filter gives different results from Photoshop :(

I've created a color balance filter for GPUImage framework: 
https://github.com/liovch/GPUImage/commit/fcc85db4fdafae1d4e41313c96bb1cac54dc93b4

Comment: Gimp color balance is only wrong with option Preserve Luminosity , that keep lightness of picture as the original. (only midtone works with this option) I'm looking for the solution of that issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. I wrote this as photoshop and flash extension via Pixel Bender
which is Adobe shader language but it is equivalent to any other shader language.
This is roughly converted Adobe ShaderLab to CG shader language.

```
Shader "Filters/ColorBalance"
{
Properties
{
    _MainTex ("Main (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    // Red, Green, Blue
    _Shadows ("shadows", Vector) = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    _Midtones ("midtones", Vector) = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    _Hilights ("hilights", Vector) = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    _Amount ("amount mix", Range (0.0, 1.0)) = 1.0
}

SubShader
{
    Tags {"RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
    Lighting Off

    Pass
    {
        ZWrite Off
        Cull Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        uniform float4 _Shadows;
        uniform float4 _Midtones;
        uniform float4 _Hilights;
        uniform float _Amount;

        uniform float pi = 3.14159265358979;            

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        // vertex output
        struct vertdata
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        vertdata vert(appdata ad)
        {
            vertdata o;
            o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, ad.vertex);
            o.texcoord = ad.texcoord;
            o.color = ad.color;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag(vertdata i) : COLOR
        {               
            float4 dst = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
            float intensity = (dst.r + dst.g + dst.b) * 0.333333333;  

            // Exponencial Shadows
            float shadowsBleed = 1.0 - intensity;
            shadowsBleed *= shadowsBleed;
            shadowsBleed *= shadowsBleed;

            // Exponencial midtones
            float midtonesBleed = 1.0 - abs(-1.0 + intensity * 2.0);
            midtonesBleed *= midtonesBleed;
            midtonesBleed *= midtonesBleed;

            // Exponencial Hilights
            float hilightsBleed = intensity;
            hilightsBleed *= hilightsBleed;
            hilightsBleed *= hilightsBleed;

            float3 colorization = dst.rgb + _Shadows.rgb * shadowsBleed + 
                                            _Midtones.rgb * midtonesBleed +
                                            _Hilights.rgb * hilightsBleed;   

            dst.rgb = lerp(dst.rgb, colorization, _Amount);
            return dst;
        }
        ENDCG
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About color balance, change red channel value for red/cyan adjustment, green for magenta/green, blue for yellow/blue. This solved problem. 
But with preserve luminosity option like in photoshop, we must keep the lightness of one pixel constant (original and color balanced pixel).

I read Gimp's source code, it solve this problem using convert RGB of new pixel  to HSL, replace L with L value of old pixel, then convert new HSL back to RGB. This RGB value remain the lightness of pixel while balancing color. However, when I test on GIMP, adjust color channel of shadow and highlight mode with "preserve luminosity" option, It's wrong.

And I am confusing how to determine shadow, mid-tone or highlight?

Answer (score -1):

**The mystery of Selective Color**

Reds are the colors, that consist of Magenta, Yellow and Black (no Cyan). However, if you select the range Reds and decrease Cyan, colors change.